# Is it possible for Facebook or Google login to return some constant and secret value for each user if login is successful?

Tags: security, rsa, facebook-login, private-key, google-signin

We have web application which has user's data encrypted with RSA public key. And for a user to access data he needs to decrypt his private key. User can decrypt his private key with his password.

Is there a way with Facebook or Google login, which will return some value that can be used as password to decrypt the private key ?

Normal Facebook or Google login only return access tokens which are not constant.